# Custom tabs with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I have a problem with implementing custom tabs, and I know i could've just used the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` for just TextView in my Layout file, but I need to show 2 another ImageViews in one Layout file.I have a custom layout for it, which I inflate like this:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int mPageCount;
    private Context mContext;
    private int[] stringResID = { R.string.serverString, R.string.localString, R.string.commonString, R.string.searchString };
    private int[] imagesResID = { R.drawable.tab1, R.drawable.tab2, R.drawable.tab3, R.drawable.tab4};

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int pageCount, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mPageCount = pageCount;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTab);
        tv.setText(stringResID[position]);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);
        img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, imagesResID[position]));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPageCount;
    }
}
```

And my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ololo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titleTab"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And call it from MainActivity like this:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TabsAdapter pagerAdapter =
                new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 4,MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if(tab != null) {
                tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
            }
        }
```

So here's the question: what am I doing wrong? Becaus this code just gives me text in tabs, without ImageView. Please help if you tried to do something like this.

Comment: Is is enough space to fit ImageView? May be it's displayed out of bounds.

Comment: @Vang yeah. the problem was in the height of layout file, yesterday I figured it out, and fixed, soon I will post the solution for this.